# BitBucket Pipelines failing to build production Angular code (staging and local machine working)

Tags: angular-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using BitBucket Pipelines to try to auto-deploy staging and production compiled code. Staging works fine, production works fine on my local server but not on Pipelines. The log of failure is below and I have no clue why it would fail:

`"build:prod": "ng build --prod"`

```
+ npm run build:prod
> mobile-app@1.1.2 build:prod /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> ng build --prod
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
<--- Last few GCs --->
[67:0x3002f10]   220826 ms: Mark-sweep 2014.9 (2069.4) -> 2004.8 (2071.6) MB, 908.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.172, current mu = 0.096) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[67:0x3002f10]   222095 ms: Mark-sweep 2016.7 (2071.6) -> 2011.3 (2074.4) MB, 1215.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.110, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
<--- JS stacktrace --->
==== JS stack trace =========================================
    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x140a8f9]
Security context: 0x325873d008d1 <JSObject>
    1: join [0x325873d155f9](this=0x1de208ef3a99 <JSArray[11]>,0x20ca5d5b37a1 <String[#1]: />)
    2: computeSourceURL [0x1d3973de0b1] [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/util.js:~441] [pc=0x873448f2a77](this=0x0e122b985d01 <Object map = 0x3ff287ea2f39>,0x05b8fbf40731 <String[#0]: >,0x0513ea418d71 <String...
 1: 0xa18150 node::Abort() [ng build --prod]
 2: 0xa1855c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng build --prod]
 3: 0xb9715e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod]
 4: 0xb974d9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod]
 5: 0xd54755  [ng build --prod]
 6: 0xd54de6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [ng build --prod]
 7: 0xd616a5 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod]
 8: 0xd62555 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod]
 9: 0xd6500c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng build --prod]
10: 0xd2ba2b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [ng build --prod]
11: 0x106dffe v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng build --prod]
12: 0x140a8f9  [ng build --prod]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! mobile-app@1.1.2 build:prod: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mobile-app@1.1.2 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-30T19_46_54_147Z-debug.log
```

This is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, if it helps:

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    production:
      - step:
          name: Build an app
          image: node:12.20.1
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run build:prod
          artifacts:
            - dist/**

      - step:
          name: Deploy to droplet
          script:
            - rsync -rzO dist/ $SSH_USER@$SSH_SERVER:/home/$WEBSITE/$URL/ --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

I also tried (one line per attempt), all of them failed:

```
- node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
- size: 2x
- ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Pipeline-fails-with-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory/qaq-p/732274

Updated my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to this and it's working for now:

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    production:
      - step:
          name: Build an app
          image: node:12.20.1
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - node
          size: 2x
          script:
            - npm install
            - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=6144
            - npm run build:prod
          artifacts:
            - dist/**

      - step:
          name: Deploy to droplet
          script:
            - rsync -rzO dist/ $SSH_USER@$SSH_SERVER:/home/$WEBSITE/$URL/ --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

The app is moderately big, so for now I hope this will work. Not sure what to do if this too starts to fail because of memory issues, once the app grows even more.

Comment: In addition to the above settings (size 2x, caches:node, export node_options), I had to restrict the docker service memory to 1024. Thanks for this tip <a href="https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Pipeline-fails-with-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory/qaq-p/732274?tempId=eyJvaWRjX2NvbnNlbnRfbGFuZ3VhZ2VfdmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMCIsIm9pZGNfY29uc2VudF9ncmFudGVkX2F0IjoxNjUyMTczNTg5MzA2fQ%3D%3D">here</a>
services:
  docker:
    memory: 1024

Answer (score 0):

for us changing the `node version` to `14.XX.xx` did work in bitbucket pipline

```
  - step:
      image: node:14.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the build locally first. It must be breaking  check your webpack configs